# mysql index for < created_at and not in

Tags: mysql, indexing

I want to get all rows older than x except those with a certain batch_id

table t:

```
id, created_at, batch_id
```

query:

```
SELECT * FROM t 
WHERE created_at < '2019-01-01' 
AND batch_id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

The query is slow even though I have < 1M rows.
I have indexes on (created_at), (batch_id) and (created_at, batch_id).
I expected the compound index to make it faster, but the DB decides to use created_at instead.

There are about 100 rows for every batch_id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A general rule for MySQL indexes is that it will employ the index for up to one range condition, and any subsequent columns in the index cannot benefit the search.

Example: If you had an index on columns `(A, B, C)`, then:

```
WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2 AND C = 3 -- uses all three columns of index

WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2 AND C < 3 -- uses all three columns of index

WHERE A = 1 AND B < 2 AND C = 3 -- uses only A and B column of index

WHERE A < 1 AND B = 2 AND C = 3 -- uses only A column of index
```

In your query, both conditions, `created_at < ...` and `batch_id not in (...)`, are range conditions. That is, they are not equality (`=`) conditions, and any type of condition other than equality counts as a range condition for this purpose.

Reversing the order of columns of your index won't change this. Since both conditions are range conditions, MySQL will only use the index for one of the two columns -- the first column of the index, whichever it is.

You saw MySQL switch to the single-column index on `created_at` because the optimizer knew it would only be able to use one column anyway, and it preferred to use the more compact index, because more index entries would fit per page.

It chose the index on `created_at` because one assumes that is more selective. You said there are about 100 rows for each `batch_id`, and up to 1 million rows total. So `batch_id NOT IN (1,2,3)` only filters out 0.03% of rows. Whereas the condition on `created_at` probably filters out a lot more than that, making it a better choice.

You said the query is still slow. You don't say how slow it is, or how fast you expect it to be. Maybe you have an unrealistic expectation for the performance.

Maybe your database server needs more powerful hardware. You don't say what specs your server has.

Maybe you are running other demanding processes on the same server, and they are competing for resources against `mysqld`.

You don't say what MySQL tuning parameters you have configured. Maybe your buffer pool is too small. You don't say what version of MySQL you use.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `INDEX(created_at)` and keep `INDEX(created_at, batch_id)`.  Then provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  If it says "Using index condition" (aka ICP), then there is a slight benefit over what you have.

This seems to be because

- With `INDEX(created_at)`, what Bill says leads the Optimizer to quit there.
- Without it, it is stuck deciding between the other two.  If it picks the composite one, only *then* does it realize it can use Index Condition Pushdown to do the `NOT IN`.  ICP provides a small benefit that was only recently implemented in MySQL.

Alas, there is no index that can do a good job with your `WHERE`.

You say the table contains `id, created_at, batch_id`?  Is that all?  If so, then the composite index is also "covering".  This provides another small speedup.  Get in the habit of spelling out the columns instead of using `*`, especially when asking questions here.  And, I would encourage saying

```
INDEX(created_at, batch_id, id)
```

to make it clear that you are expecting that do "cover" this:

```
SELECT id, created_at, batch_id  FROM t
    WHERE created_at < '2019-01-01' 
      AND batch_id NOT IN (1,2,3)
```